# Solve in integers $x+\frac1{y+\frac1z}=\frac{10}7$

Tags: integers

> Solve in integers
>   $$x+\frac1{y+\frac1z}=\frac{10}7$$

My work:

1) $$\frac{xyz+x+z}{yz+1}=\frac{10}7$$

2) Solutions: $x=1, y=2, z=3$ and $x=2, y=-2, z=4$

Comment: Your work looks correct, but I just need to verify it.

Comment: For positive integers, of course 
$$\frac{10}{7}=1+\frac{3}{7}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{7}{3}}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3}}$$
and you may use the uniqueness of [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), canonical form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x=1$:

$$\frac{yz+1+z}{yz+1} = \frac{10}{7}$$
$$7yz + 7 + 7z = 10yz+10$$
$$3yz-7z+3=0$$
$$z=-\frac{3}{3y-7}$$

and setting $3y-7$ equal to $-3,-1,1$, and $3$ gives the only solution $(1, 2, 3)$.

And when $x=2$:
$$\frac{2yz+2+z}{yz+1} = \frac{10}{7}$$
$$14yz + 14 + 7z = 10yz+10$$
$$4yz+7z+4=0$$
$$z=-\frac{4}{4y+7}$$

and setting $4y+7$ equal to $-4, -2, -1, 1, 2$ and $4$ gives the only solution $(2, -2, 4)$.

Comment: It is quite hard to determine that $x=1$ and $x=2$ are the only possibilities for $x$. I'll now correct my comment: youcan show that if the expression lies between $1$ and $2$, then it must be equal to $\frac{3}{2}$, $\frac{4}{3}$, $\frac{5}{4}, \cdots, \frac{n+1}{n}$, and $\frac{10}{7}$ is not in this list.